# Is there way a to use join query in Azure Data factory When copying data from Sybase source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to ingest data from Sybase source in to Azure datalake. I am ingesting several tables using a Watermark table that has tables names from Sybase source. Now process works fine for a full import, however we are trying to Import tables every 15 minutes to feed a dashboard. We don't need to ingest whole table as we don't need all the data from it.

Table doesn't have dateModified or any kind of incremental id to perform an incremental load. Only way of filtering out unwanted data is to perform a join on to another look up table at source and then using "filter" value in "Where" clause.

Is there a way we can perform this in Azure data factory ? I have attached my current pipeline screenshot just to make it a bit more clear. 
[image]

Comment: Can you try using lookup active to run a query to get all the table name from the Sybase  dataset, then using foreach and if condition to decide if need copy the table data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate @LeonYue , foreeach and if condition is already working. My query was in regards to how to use different Joins and where conditions on source table using one dynamic pipeline. I have found the solution

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for looking in to this. I have managed to find a solution. I was using a Watermark table to ingest about 40 tables using one pipeline. My only issue was how to use join and "where" filter in my query without hard coding it in pipeline. I have achieved this by adding "Join" and "Where" fields in my Watermark table and then passing it in "Query" as @{item ().Join} @{item().Where). It Worked like a magic.